# Submeter formulário usando modal bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal

estou tentando submeter um formulário contido no modal boostrap, mas não sei como realizar esta ação.

Vejam abaixo o meu código:

Pagina Principal:

```
<div id="idDivModal4" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-block btn-primary top10 btn-sm" href='#idDivModal4' role='button' data-toggle='modal' data-load-remote='atualizar-status/<?php echo $codigo;?>' data-remote-target='#idDivModal4 .modal-content' aria-hidden='true' > Atualizar Status</a>
```

Página (atualizar-status) contendo form do modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">

<select name="campo_status " id="campo_status " class="form-control div-campo-status" required>
<option value="Sim">Sim</option>
<option value="Não">Não</option>
</select>

<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
<a class="btn-atualizar-status">Atualizar</a>
</div>
```

Na página Principal, inclui o seguinte jquery:

```
$('#idDivModal4').on('click', '.btn-atualizar-status', function(){
{
     var campo_status = $(this).parent().find('.div-campo-status').val();  
     alert(campo_status);
});
```

Acontece que ele dispara o evento clique, porém, ao clicar no botão, ele mostra a variavel como "undefined". Como eu consigo resgatar o valor do campo select?

Qualquer ajuda agradeço =D

Answer (score 1):

Adicione uma id a tag  do Modal, após, basta pegar o elemento pela id e adicionar a função onclick, por exemplo:

```
$("#atualizar").click(function() {

alert ('Testando o clique no botão atualizar');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode capturar o evento direto do botão. Não precisa passar pelos métodos modal e find.

```
$(".btn-atualizar-status").on('click', function() {
    alert('Testando o clique no botão atualizar');
});
```

Comment: Ola Lucas, testei desse jeito, mas não deu certo. quando clico no botão, nada acontece.

Comment: Usei o " $('#idDivModal4').on('click', '.btn-atualizar-status', function(){   " e funcionou =D